# DMARC settings with plesk

Tags: dns, plesk, spf, dkim, dmarc

My domain DKIM and SPF records looks success.

Authentication Report is:

SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   pass
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

I need to DMARC configuration on Plesk panel. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be just as simple as adding a new TXT record for "_dmarc" on your domain.

The contents would look something like this:

```
v=DMARC1;adkim=r;aspf=r;p=none;sp=reject;
```

Head over to http://dmarc.org/ for more information.

You can test your record using this command on Windows or your favorite flavor of Unix:

```
nslookup -query=txt _dmarc.yourdomain.org
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add TXT record for DMARC that specify where you should receive reports from recipient organization (gmail, yahoo etc.) that can look like this `v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:dmarc@yourdomain.com; ruf=mailto:dmarc@yourdomain.com;`.
Here you can find short helpful manual from google for example https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466563?hl=en